# Why is this dot only appearing on the safari browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I was wondering how I can remove the red dot at the end of my text animation word switch. I have no idea if this could be a browser issue. However, it seems to come up on multiple devices and browsers I tested the webpage on.

**The red dot is appearing only on the safari browser.**

Look at the end of the word "graphic designer" you will see the red dot.

Here is a link to my site code using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgkg3syj/2/)

```
          <div class="header-content">
             <h1 class="maintxt rotateInUpLeft animated">Hi, welcome to my portfolio</h1>
             <h2 class="maintxt rotateInUpLeft animated">My name is Liam Docherty</h2>
             <h3 class="cd-headline rotateInUpLeft animated loading-bar">
                <span>I'm a</span>
                <span class="cd-words-wrapper">
                <b class="is-visible">Front-End Web Developer</b>
                <b>Graphic Designer</b>
                </span>
             </h3>
             <hr class="content-divider">
```

Comment: Kinda looks like its left over from your animated red line. Not sure why though. Like some kind of painting error. It seems to go away if I change the red line's final `is-loading` width to 99% instead of 100%. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/vgkg3syj/5/). Give you any clues?

Comment: I'm not on a mac and I couldn't get any browser I have installed to show the dot.  I'm guessing it's a remnant of the first underline.  Have you tried adding a bit of a delay between the two animations and maybe fading the first one out.  It would look less jarring and probably fix your problem at the same time.

Comment: @showdev Thanks that actually managed to fix my issue. Much appreciated.